# VID and PID (how to acquire Product ID)

Tags: driver, pid, signature, vendor

The company where I work has asked me to get involved in the whole signing our usb devices thing. We are selling our software, together with these usbs that act as a licensing device for the software that we provide.

We need it so Windows can recognize the drivers for our USB.

For the past week I've been doing some research regarding the whole VID and PID USB Driver signing.

What I've found so far is that the best solution for us was to have a VID in the first place (a vendor ID). So we got one from [USB-IF](http://www.usb.org/home) for 5000$.

Now the thing is, I do not really know what should happen next. I know that our company should 'create' (not sure if this is the right terminology) a PID (product ID).

I cannot seem to find anywhere any information about acquiring a PID that should work together with the VID. I might be wrong, but I think I read somewhere that somehow I should get involved with Microsoft. I've looked into it, but I cannot seem to find any information about this on their website.

How exactly can I get a PID? What are the steps towards getting it?

Comment: Painful, that's five grand you'll never get back.  The PID+VID does not have anything to do with signing.  Its only role is to help the OS to find the proper device driver to load.  You only need it when you create the USB device from scratch and requires writing the firmware, the device driver and the .inf installer for the driver.  And is useless for license verification, it can be trivially spoofed.  Five grant buys you a box full of hasp dongles from a vendor like Gemalto.  Plug and play, they also give you the library to make it secure in your own code, the weak link.

Comment: I might've written the question wrong though; because, besides the signing process, we would like the OS (usually, Windows 10) to recognize the driver automatically that is provided with the software. Right now, for a new client, we have to take them through the whole process where you have to disable the signed driver enforcement from Windows, then we'd have to load the driver manually, so that the USB can work. That's what we want to get rid off. In this context, is the VID+PID still useless?

Comment: This also has nothing to do with PID+VID.  You have to get your driver certified by Microsoft WHQL.  After they tested it to ensure it does not destabilize the OS you get a certificate back from them.  You sign the driver with your own *and* Microsoft's certificate and now it can be installed on the user's machine without hassle.

Comment: Just to make sure; are you talking about this? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/test/hlk/windows-hardware-lab-kit ; which implies that I'd have to go through the entire process of the dongle testing (hardware testing) which should spit out a log of some form, which later, should be sent to Microsoft and then they can assist me with the certification? If I'm wrong, could you kindly direct me to the right information (website) regarding the certification?